# CRTP implementation in c#

Tags: c#, performance, class, inheritance, crtp

I'm trying to implement `Curiously recurring template pattern(CRTP)` in c#.

here is some code i wrote.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;


// Curiously recurring template pattern in c#
namespace MyApp
{
    public class Program 
    {
        public static void Main (string[] arg)
        {
            new Child().CallChildMethod();        
        }
    } 

    public abstract class Base <T> where T: Base<T>, new ()
    {
        // Game loop
        void Upate ()
        { 
            Method ();
        }

        public void CallChildMethod ()
        {
            T t = (T)this;
            t?.Method ();
        }

        public void Method () 
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Base Method!");
        }
    }
    
    public class Child: Base <Child> 
    {
        public new void Method ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Child Method!");
        }
    }
}
```

In output i'm getting

```
Base Method!
```

but my code should print

```
Child Method!
```

**any idea?**

#### Expected

I want to access `child` class object in `base` class instead of `overriding` base methods and please suggest is there any other way to do the same?.

Comment: See the combined 2 answers above that should answer your question as to why this occurs.

Comment: Also why not just use polymorphism with `virtual`/`override`? `new` is kind of a code smell I would say.

Comment: @GuruStron i you're overriding a function in a update it takes cost!

Comment: I highly doubt that it is relevant in 99.(9)% of scenarios. I highly doubt that it is relevant in yours and the cost of CRTP will be less.

Comment: @GuruStron do you know how to implement this in c#?

Comment: @CoderCoder can you please show the actual example when and how you need to implement something like this? What is rationale behind this?

Comment: I can't verify that `new` vs. `virtual/override` is more efficient but for arguments sake let's say it is. The increase in efficiency is so minimal and insignificant it is not worth the trouble when compared to the complexity and obscurity you are adding to the code by doing it this way. *If* performance is paramount to the degree this does matter then maybe you are using the wrong platform for the job. Chances are though there are other operations in the code that could benefit from optimization that would have a greater impact compared to doing this.

Comment: Looking at the behavior desired and the inheritance structure you have the way to go about achieving the output is by marking the parent method as `virtual` and the child method with `override`.

Comment: @Igor let suppose Base.Method is calls in update

Comment: @CoderCoder _"let suppose Base.Method is calls in update"_ - and?

Comment: @GuruStron then method will be overrides on every frame in child class and you can also see updated answer

Comment: @CoderCoder _" then method will be overrides on every frame in child class"_ - and? =)

Comment: and it will take perfomance cost :-) that's the problem

Comment: @CoderCoder If virtual method dispatch is too costly for you then I doubt that C# is right language for you. Also you should measure first if this is actual bottleneck in your app (I highly doubt it). If you want to go away from the virtual method dispatch you can try to look into generic + value types +interfaces (generic method/type will be recompiled for every value type). But it is rarely needed.

Comment: @CoderCoder running managed language takes performance cost (and sometimes quite a huge one). Can you prove that virtual method dispatch cost is actual problem for your app? Have you profiled it?

Comment: @GuruStron check this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/266333/Virtual-Methods-Can-Cause-Performance-Overheads)

Comment: @CoderCoder that is an article written by someone who knows nothing about proper benchmarking. If you reorder statements then it can give you completely other results proving that virtual dispatch is faster.

Comment: @GuruStron so what is conclusion?

Comment: @GuruStron can i use `delegate` to cache function in a variable and then call it in update?

Comment: @CoderCoder avoid [premature optimization](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil), profile, find bottlenecks in your actual app, benchmark using right tools against your concrete infrastructure and if needed [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).